# How to set value for objective-c property function using ObjCRuntime c#

Tags: c#, objective-c

How to set value in some objective c class using ObjCRuntime. For example analogue for next code in obj-c:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconImage = pathToImage;
```

Comment: How is `ObjCRuntime` relevant? How about just `NSApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconImage = pathToImage;`? (Assuming `pathToImage` is of type `NSImage`.)

Comment: Please don't misuse tags. The `monodevelop` tag is completely irrelevant to your questions.

Comment: Needed because MacCatalyst does not have NSApplication.SharedApplication